# Fetch json data if json still not created

Tags: javascript, php, json

This is a sample of my form in php:

```
    echo "<form method='GET' action='queries.php'>
           <label>name1</label>
           <input type='checkbox' name='name1'/>
           <label>name2</label>
           <input type='checkbox' name='name2'/>
           <label>name3</label>
           <input type='checkbox' name='name3'/>
           <input type='submit' name='sendData' value='Send'/>
          </form>";
```

I take all the values in $_GET and i want to pass them in json to the frontend

```
$data = isset($_GET) ? $_GET : 0; 
 
 if (count($data)>0) {
   $res = $data;
   echo json_encode($res);
  } else {
   $noData -> Message = "No data passed";
    echo json_encode($noData); 
  }
```

The problem is when i try to fetch with any http request the json generated from the form. I always get the $noData json instead of $res.

I need to use the data generated on a subsequent request. What would you suggest me to use to do that?

Comment: How many variables do you think you need for one array?

Comment: If you submit the form to queries.php, then queries.php should run and be able to read the data. If you want to access that information on a _subsequent_ request (not the one which receives the form data), then you need to store the submitted data somewhere more permanent first, and then fetch it from there. Does that help? Your question was a bit unclear, to be honest.

Comment: Is this an AJAX action? If so, `echo json_encode($_GET)` should suffice, without any conditions whatsoever. If not, then the whole thing doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: Ppl normally test `isset($_GET("sendData"))` to see if the form is submitted. If you submit using AJAX, you will need to set that yourself

Comment: If you are getting the `$noData` responce then apart from a missing object instantiation in the sample code you show us, there is no $_GET being passed to this code

Comment: I think you ought to show us all the code, and the file names of the code because there is a little to much missing from this sample code

Comment: Side note: trying to do `count` on an integer (you try to set `$data` to `0` in the ternary) will yield a warning: `Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable`.

Comment: @ADyson you centered my problem. I need to use the data generated on a subsequent request. What would you suggest me to use to do that?

Comment: @mplungjan thx i will fix it

Comment: @El_Vanja thx u too i will fix this too

Comment: @RiggsFolly i don't get the question. What do you mean?

Comment: `What would you suggest me to use to do that`...I already told you. You need to store the data somewhere more permanent. Maybe in a file, or a database perhaps. Or, if you only need the data for this user within their current usage session, then you could store it in the PHP Session. Depends on your exact requirements. But the important thing to learn from this is that web applications are _stateless_ - information held in variables does not persist between different HTTP requests. If you want to keep the information submitted by the user, you need to have code to store and then retrieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the data somewhere more permanent. Maybe in a file, or a database perhaps.

Or, if you only need the data for this user within their current usage session, then you could store it in the PHP Session. It depends on your exact requirements.

But the important thing to learn from this is that web applications are *stateless* - and therefore information held in ordinary PHP variables does not persist between different HTTP requests. If you want to keep the information submitted by the user, you need to have code to store it (and then more code to retrieve the correct information on a subsequent request).